# Cannot get Route53 domain to point to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is what I did:

- Registered Domain Name jthinkws.com (with fasthosts)
- Created new trusted Zone in Route 53 for jthinkws.com
- Added new record Set for jthinkws.com

  - Name :search.jthinkws.com
  - Type :CName
  - Value:jthinkws.elasticbeanstalk.com
- Waited 12 hours for it to propogate

But still if I enter http://search.jthinkws.com in a web-browser it is not found

Have I done this right ?

*** Update ***

Just searched on whois and see name servers are still set to

- Name Server: NS1.LIVEDNS.CO.UK
- Name Server: NS2.LIVEDNS.CO.UK
- Name Server: NS3.LIVEDNS.CO.UK

do I have to do something to get them changed to the Amazon ones ?

*** Update ***

Changes to nameservers made and propogated yet still search.jthinkws.com does not work, why would this be ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the nameserver records on fasthost to match the ones gives from Route53. 
When I run "dig jthinkws.com any" in my bash shell I get the following responds:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> jthinkws.com any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24700
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jthinkws.com.          IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
jthinkws.com.       3599    IN  SOA ns1.livedns.co.uk. admin.jthinkws.com. 1404204424   10800 3600 604800 3600
jthinkws.com.       3599    IN  NS  ns2.livedns.co.uk.
jthinkws.com.       3599    IN  NS  ns3.livedns.co.uk.
jthinkws.com.       3599    IN  A   213.171.195.105
jthinkws.com.       3599    IN  NS  ns1.livedns.co.uk.

;; Query time: 315 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul  2 14:58:42 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 155
```

The NS records must be AWS records for Route53 to work. Check out [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/R53Example.html) getting started guide.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was done by Amazon, okay Ive done now will just have to wait thx.One thing I don't underdstand is the difference between 'Migrate Domain' and 'Add Domain', I mean Ive created a domain and allocating it to Route53 is that Add or Migrate ?

Comment: There isn't much of a difference other then in Migrate you have a step to copy DNS records from your old provider into the Route53. As a side note, I would recommend using A records instead of CNAME. CNAME sometimes conflict with other txt records. Should you have a load balancer in your beanstalk, I suggest using using the [Alias](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowToAliasRRS.html) feature, for a single instance use the assigned elastic ip.

Comment: could you elaborate on this CNAME problem ?

Comment: Actually, Route53 doesn't even allow you to have a CNAME and a TXT on the same domain. Try adding a txt record on search.jthinkws.com and you'll see the error message. Also a lot of services require TXT record to prove you own the domain ([google mail](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/176792?hl=en) or [load testing](http://loader.io/) services for example).

Comment: Im unclear if you are saying CNAME won't work or simply thats its not the best way, but this is just a webservice used by customers I don't gmail ecetra, I'm simply looking for the simplest setup to get it working. Now the dns changes have been propagated around the internet yet still search.jthinkws.com does nothing, please why would that be ?

Comment: its actually working now, maybe the dns changes hadn't fully propogated round, I also tested out using the load balancer alias with the www.jthinkws.com domain and that is working as well, so all good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need use the Amazon Ones for name servers; That is the connection you would establish with your domain name and Route53.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the hosted zone for jthinkws.com.  Go to Record sets, there will be an entry for type NS. You will need to copy these name servers endpoints and update it in the DNS provider (fasthosts) for the domain jthinkws.com

-Santhosh